# Prompted with Object doesn't support his property or method

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to update the 1 of the field on the right section after selecting 1 of the button on left section but was prompted with the run-time error 438 code.

I have tried changing the element and attribution of the last row of my code but nothing seems to work.

Below is part of my VBA script:

```vb
Sub BrowseToWebTest1()

Dim ie As Object
Dim the_button_elements As Object
Dim button_element As Object
Dim radioButton As Object
Dim radioButtons As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

ie.navigate "company system web"
ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

Set doc = ie.document

Set the_button_elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each button_element In the_button_elements
    If button_element.getAttribute("onclick") = "CreateAcqCase();" Then
        button_element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next button_element

Call doc.getElementByName(“TransactionID”).setAttribute(“value”, “test”)
```

Below is the DOM Explorer code:

```html
<input name="$PAcqCaseCreation$pTransactionID" class="leftJustifyStyle" id="TransactionID" style="width: 175px;" type="text" maxlength="15" value="" data-ctl='["TextInput"]' minchars="15" validationtype="minchars" data-changed="false">
```

Hopefully someone call help so that i can update fields accordingly. By the way I am using IE11 and Window 10

Comment: Try to replace the last line of code with this and check whether it helps to set the value or not.  doc.getElementById(“TransactionID”).value="test"

Answer (score 0):

1) You have a mistake here:

```
doc.getElementByName(“TransactionID”).setAttribute(“value”, “test”)
```

The method is `getElementsByName` , notice the `s` indicating plural - a collection is returned. As it is a collection, you will need to supply an appropriate index to target the element of interest.

2) Also, you have introduced smart “ where you want ".

3) Neither `call` keyword, nor parantheses are needed.

4) The `name` attribute is:

```
name="$PAcqCaseCreation$pTransactionID"
```

Whereas the `id` attribute is:

```
id="TransactionID"
```

`id` is likely unique and a better selector (and is singular, so no `s` or index):

```
doc.getElementId("TransactionID").setAttribute "value", "test"
```

Otherwise,

```
doc.getElementsByName("$PAcqCaseCreation$pTransactionID")(0).setAttribute "value", "test"
```

This would be assuming first element in collection is the correct; otherwise, change the index.

5) You can replace all this (and remove the associated declarations):

```
Set the_button_elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each button_element In the_button_elements
    If button_element.getAttribute("onclick") = "CreateAcqCase();" Then
        button_element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next button_element
```

With one line:

```
doc.querySelector("[onclick='CreateAcqCase();']").Click
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have changed to  doc.getElementsByName("$PAcqCaseCreation$pTransactionID")(0).setAttribute "value", "test" as recommended but I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Could this be because my update is on new window and it makes some difference in the scripting?

Comment: Possibly. Try the id version

Comment: Would you be able to provide me the script as I am pretty new in this? I have been searching high & low for the appropriate codes but nothing worked. Just to be cleared I am to update the field which is on a new section on the right hand side of the same page after I clicked on CreateAcqCase.

Comment: You need proper page load waits While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4:DoEvents:Wend  That should appear after .Navigate and after you click on the CresteAcqCase then doc.getElementId("TransactionID").setAttribute "value", "test"  or doc.getElementId("TransactionID").value = "Test"

Comment: It doesn't work. It still gave me the same error message.

Comment: Run-Time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: You said in your comment,'Could this be because my update is on new window'. Do you mean clicking a button opens a new window or new tab? If yes than you may need to loop through IE windows and create and assign that window to IE object. than you can try to set the value for that input.

Comment: After selecting the CreateAcqCase button it did open up a new tab. Would you be able to provide me the script to loop through the tab?

Comment: I’m still confused by your error given it’s not about object not found

Comment: I am getting the error (Object doesn't support this property or method) when I used the script you suggested. I am not sure is this due to the new tab open after CreateAcqCase button selected? Hope you advice.

Comment: @user9750397, Try to refer this example may help you to loop through IE tabs. you can try to find specific tab using it's title. Ref: https://textuploader.com/11gvi Further you can try to modify it as per your own requirement and try to implement it in your code.